# What invariants distinguish these three-folds?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $a,b$ be two positive integers and everything is over $\mathbb C$. Let's denote by $S_{a,b}$ the hypersurface $$\{x^ay+z^bt=1\}\subset \mathbb A^4.$$
Can we distinguish the $S_{a,b}$'s up to isomorphism? What invariants would be useful in this case?

Comment: A naive response on the level of Shafarevich: isomorphic affine hypersurfaces in A^4 have birational projectivizations, hence isomorphic spaces of regular 3 forms. Thus hypersurfaces of different degrees > 4, are not isomorphic. It would also be fun to look at the projection to A^2, (x,z,y,t)--> (y,t) and study the resulting family of plane curves fibering the 3 fold.  Here one naturally looks at the plane curve of singular fibers.

Comment: @roysmith I am confused. All of these $3$-folds are rational (we can write $t$ as a rational function of $(x,y,z)$), so any smooth projective completions of them have no nonzero regular $3$-forms.  I don't see how you are going to use this.

Comment: thank you David!  i admit did i not check non singularity.  is that the problem?  i didn't think too long on this, just trying to get the discussion started on a question with no answers.  my apologies if this was misleading.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the morphism $S_{m,n}\to \mathbb{A}^2_{*}=\mathbb{A}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ given by the projection to $(x,z)$. Then, it is a locally trivial $\mathbb{A}^1$-bundle. This latter is trivial for the Euclidean topology so $S_{m,n}$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^2_{*}\times \mathbb{A}^1$. However, these can give non-isomorphic varieties.

In fact $S_{a,b}$ is isomorphic to $S_{a',b'}$ if $a+b=a'+b'$, but apart from this, the question is open (except maybe for $S_{1,1}\simeq\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ which is probably not isomorphic to the other ones). For more details on this, look at the paper  "On exotic affine $3$-spheres" of A. Dubouloz and D. Finston http://www.ams.org/journals/jag/2014-23-03/S1056-3911-2014-00612-3/home.html